# LXDE autostart application runs twice

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, autostart

I have connected an LCD to my Rapsberry Pi which is acting as a frame buffer device (booting and desktop visible when running Raspbian). To control the LCD I use Python and Pygame, which works perfectly.
But I would like to auto start this application.
The only way I could which resulted in the Python application taking control over the LCD is by using LXDE autostart. But the application then runs twice! My guess this is due to the fact that I also run vnc, so I have two desktops which both autostart the application.
Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Take a closer look to `init.d`, which executes scripts on system start-up. You can find some hints [here](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) and [here](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/).

Comment: while i don't know why your application is started multiple times (maybe LCDE also tries to restore the applications that were running when you last logged out?), you could implement a singleton (e.g. via a lock-file), that would only allow a single instance of your application to run at any time to circumvent the problem.

Comment: I have tried through init.d before. This results in the LCD showing the desktop and the application is not running. If I start the script from init.d by hand, it starts correctly. I therefore conclude that my application needs to run after the LCD has been initialised.

Comment: are you running vncserver at startup?

Comment: Yes, I run vncserver at startup.